# Will a particle's spin evolve abruptly if the magnetic field it's in changed abrubptly?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, quantum-spin

If a particle (say electron) was placed in a magnetic field with only a z-component ( $B_0 \hat{k}$ ), then according to the equations $$H = - \mu \ .B \ \ \ \quad \quad \quad \quad\mu =\gamma S $$
the system's Hamiltonian is $H = -\gamma B_0 S_z$

With that I used the TDSE to get the eigenstate for this particular system

In the next part of the excercise, the magnetic field "instantly" shifted its direction towards the y axis, and I was asked to, once again, find the eigenstates.

My question is, does the state vary instantly with the magnetic field, or should I expect the initial conditions of the new system to match the final state of the old system (right before the magnetic field shifted).

Comment: I'm puzzled why you need to use the TDSE. To find the eigenstates, can you not just diagonalize the Hamiltonians?

Comment: The state doesn't change instantly. The eigenstates may change instantly, but if you change the magnetic field, the system will remain the same, and start evolving according to the new magnetic field.

Comment: The hamiltonian is related to the **derivative** of the wavefunction. If you change brutally the magnetic field, you will brutally change the Hamiltonian and thus the derivative of the wavefunction, not the wavefunction in itself.

Answer (score 0):

The state does not vary instantly.

One way to see how the energy changes with a new magnetic field would be to physically *measure* the energy of the system after some time $t$. With Dirac notation, for your problem, if it's a spin $1/2$ system, $|\psi(t=0)\rangle = |\pm\rangle_z$ (usually it's convention to omit the subscript $z$) which would then time evolve according to the coefficient $e^{-iE_{\pm}t/\hbar}$. But first you would need to project the new $|\psi\rangle_y$ onto the z plane before multiplying by the time evolving coefficient which would the finally give $|\psi(t)\rangle$.

Comment: Why do you need to project the state? Is somebody or something measuring it?

Comment: Look, I'm just elaborating on their question to give them a deeper understanding of what occurs when the magnetic field changes. Our knowledge of the system depends on us measuring it, but sure, no one need measure it. I answered their question in the first sentence which you concurred with. You don't NEED to measure the state, I'm only outlining a procedure if you were interested measuring the energy of the system